# Retina display, ImageView showing wrong size image set to UIViewContentModeTopRight

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, retina-display

I have an app that compares different finishes.

I have 2 image views side by side, set to `UIViewContentModeTopLeft` and `UIViewContentModeTopRight`. The left one shows the left side and the right one shows the right side of the image, so you can seamlessly compare the images. You can drag any of the finishes to either side to view them.

My problem is the retina display is displaying image at double size so you only see a top quadrant in each image view. If I halve the image size using a resizing function it works, but a non-retina display shows the small, full image in the image view instead of just the half.

If I run the resizing function and read back the size, I get this back, below is my resizing function:

> 2012-12-11 09:48:24.148 srg[20290:c07] set image width: 700.000000 height: 525.000000
>       2012-12-11 09:48:24.198 srg[20290:c07] image size: {1400, 1050}

```
+ (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: So you are drawing two images next to eachother? What is the size you are actually trying to draw them at?

Comment: Left half is 350 x 525, right half is the 350 x 525 on an iPad, the images should be 700x525 when whole but only half is displayed on this split screen section of the app.  Everything will be scaled down when device is an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the images and create a double the normal size image and set it in your project with the name `"image"@2x.png` this way, xcode will automatically use the @2x image for retina display devices and the regular `image.png` for non retina devices. Or if retina devices are making your image to large, then make the image half the size and set it to @2x and that should solve the problem. Hope that helps.